# Matching outlets to junction boxes and their covers, by example

Tags: electrical, receptacle, junction-box

**Please note:** Since creating this question, several community members have explained to me that since I'm running 12/2 and 10/3 I will have a grounding wire and so the electrification concern I mentioned below in the question is null and void. **However** I really don't like the look of metal (remember these outlets will be fully exposed and tapconned to basement walls) and would prefer the look of PVC, but that is only aesthetic. If it is near impossible to find a PVC solution and super easy to find a metal-based solution, I will totally accept the metal solution and would consider just painting the metal a color of my choosing.

#### Background context and project specs

I am planning out the installation of 3 new outlets in my basement. I have a buddy that will actually install the breakers and do the wiring in the electrical panel (he is a licensed electrician) but I want to take on:

1. Installing the junction boxes
2. Running the (Romex) cable from the *area where my service panel is* (remember: I'm not doing the live electrical hookup) to the junction boxes, including running the cable through protective sleeves (I'll explain in a minute)
3. Connecting the cable to the outlets
4. Fastening the outlets into the junction boxes and attaching faceplate/covers to them

So I would do all the "outlet-end" work and my buddy will do all the "panel-end" work (the actual hookup). And yes, he will absolutely verify I did everything correctly before he turns anything on. The point of this exercise is to get me more familiar with doing light electrical work around the house, while doing it safely and in a controlled manner.

So, these outlets will be several feet off the ground and the junction boxes must attach to the concrete block foundation of my basement walls. The junctions must contain a knockout on the top of them so I can run the Romex cable into them from the top (this is more aesthetic for me than anything else). I want the Romex cable encased in a conduit to act as a protective sleeve (and nothing more) and I want that conduit to run from the top of the outlet all the way up to the "ceiling" of my basement which contains open-faced floor joists (that hold up the 1st story of my house). At that point, the conduit/protective sleeve would end, and the Romex cable will run along the bottom of my floor joists and attached/secured to them by staples. I obviously need to leave several feet coiled up once I get to the service panel, to give my buddy plenty of wiggle room to make his connections.

Further, I am really not a huge fan of metal junction boxes and metal conduit. I'm not a fan of how they look and whether its uneducated or not, they just sort of freak me out and make me worry about whether they could ever become electrified in the event of a fault. If you tell me metal is the **only** way I can go here, I would of course use them, but I would appreciate an explanation of *why* so that I can understand. Otherwise, I'm looking to go with PVC junction boxes, PVC outlet covers and PVC conduit/protective sleeves.

So here are my 3 outlets. We have a NEMA 14-30 240V 30A outlet that will be getting a (240v) GFCI breaker at the panel. Then we have two (2) 3-pronged duplex outlets (20A 125VAC). One of them is a GFCI outlet and one of them has a pair of USB chargers in it. I will be running 12/2 Romex NM-B to both duplexes and 10/3 Romex NM-B to the NEMA. The Romex must fit inside the 1/2" conduit protective sleeves (**please speak up if thats not possible!!!**) It is important to note that all 3 outlets will be at different locations in the basement and will not be sharing cables, conduit or junction boxes. They are all fully independent. Without further ado:

[image]

#### What I've done so far

I am trying to purchase junction boxes, outlet covers, conduit and conduit-to-junction connectors for each of these 3 outlets and I'm having a tough time finding products that will get the job done given all my constraints. I have found two products off of a bigbox retailer website:

[image]

The [junction box I found](https://www.lowes.com/pd/TayMac-1-Gang-Gray-PVC-Weatherproof-New-Work-Old-Work-Standard-Switch-Outlet-Wall-Electrical-Box/4005489?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-elc-_-ggl-_-LIA_ELC_206_Conduit-Fittings-Boxes-_-4005489-_-local-_-0-_-0&ds_rl=1286981&gclid=CjwKCAiAlfqOBhAeEiwAYi43F_VvR3p-koUjlvXs0vttvndXlgdG8GImr48kmBOCadhC9DNonl4BmRoCeBgQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) seems to meet all my needs:

- made out of PVC
- looks like I can attach it to my basement walls with tapcon screws
- looks like it will fit all 3 outlets (**though the wider NEMA 14-30 might be a tight fit...**)
- has knockouts on the top for the protective sleeve conduit

  - **I have a long section of 1/2" PVC conduit and it *appears* I can run the Romex through it and connect the conduit to the box with some type of connector**
- looks like it has screw holes that would be compatible with all 3 outlets (for fastening them to the junction box)

The [cover I found for the 2 duplexes](https://www.lowes.com/pd/TayMac-1-Gang-Rectangle-Plastic-Weatherproof-Electrical-Box-Cover/1000478661) also seems to check all the boxes as well:

- made out of PVC
- seems to fit the junction box above
- seems compatible with both duplex outlets

**The only straggler that I wasn't able to find a product for is the faceplate/cover for the NEMA 14-30 junction box/outlet, and I would appreciate any suggestions.**

#### My actual question

Will the products I've listed above work for my needs (given all the constraints/specs), and if not, why **and** what products *would* work instead?

Comment: I'm wondering why you've chosen a weatherproof cover for outlets in your basement. Does it often rain down there ... ?

Comment: 1 - As noted already, no need for weatherproof covers in a basement. 2 - Don't actually need "covers", just faceplates, which are available in white, ivory and other colors and various grades of plastic (or the metal you don't want). 3 - What's wrong with metal boxes? If covered up you won't see them, if not covered up (open walls) I think they give a great "look", and in any case if properly grounded they actually provide *more* protection rather than less;

Comment: Yes @brhans we have had upstairs toilet flanges fail and flood the basement. I am not opposed to something less hardcore but that seemed to check all the boxes.

Comment: 4 - GFCI double breaker for one, GFCI/receptacle for another - but the USB receptacle should have GFCI too in a basement - can't get that all combined, so either daisy chain from another location or put in a double gang box with GFCI/receptacle + USB/receptacle, or put in a GFCI breaker; 5 - Conduit as protection on open walls is a good idea, though you can also (I'm pretty sure) just have it stapled/secured to the wall - i.e., the protection is required when *inside* the wall to prevent damage from nails/screws going into the wall; 6 - going through joists should be *through* holes not under.

Comment: And @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact (1) see my answer for brhans above, (2) awesome that I don't needs covers, I would just ask that if you provide an answer that you provide links to what you are talking about, and (3) these are open/uncovered (my basement is not finished) and I personally don't like the look of metal. I would only choose metal if thats my only option.

Comment: The whole point of the ground wire is that the metal box is grounded, so in the case of a fault current returns to  the breaker and it trips. Plus, it stands up to arc faults much better. Even less current in the case of the GFCI protected ones. All of these are easy to find parts for in 4x4 steel boxes. PVC is going to be a harder shopping trip, for sure, especially the covers. In Re: below, it can be painted or covered, of course.

Comment: Thanks @Ecnerwal, if you are able to find junction boxes, covers/plates, etc. that meet these needs, its OK if they are metal, I would just prefer PVC because (to me) metal is ugly given how the rest of my basement looks. But I would accept metal-based solutions if thats monumentally easier.

Comment: Metal is absolutely not the only option. But (a) Harper recommends metal and (b) my personal electrician (I do the easy stuff, he does the hard stuff) recommends metal, so no real question for me. You can use metal boxes and plastic faceplates together with wiremold or wood strips for vertical protection and then you really won't see much of the metal.

Comment: Pulling NM-B _cable_ through conduit is strongly _not_ recommended. Granted, you're planning on a single straight run, so it won't be _really_ bad, but pulling _cable_ through conduit is a pain. Instead, look at pulling individual THHN wires through - it will be _much_ easier. You cannot, though, run individual THHN along the bottom of your joists, so you'd have to transition to cable there or make the entire run in conduit. An advantage of using wires & metal conduit/boxes, is that the entire conduit system becomes the ground & you don't have to pull a ground wire, saving $$$ copper.

Comment: So far as metal and aesthetics are concerned: there's no safety or code reason why you couldn't paint the metal parts. Degrease, give a coat of spray or brush-on paint, and then install them. Do note though that metal electrical parts are galvanized and many paints will not bond well to galvanized surfaces. The Rustoleum Latex Aluminum Primer is one of few that are compatible with galvanized; it can be top-coated with oil-based enamels, latex enamels, and aerosols.

Comment: Not sure 10/3 in 1/2” conduit is going to be legal for fill. Maybe somebody has the math at the tip of their fingertips…

Comment: For your standard, 20A duplex outlets, I'd think a standard "jumbo" sized wall plate [such as this](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Eaton-1-Gang-White-Single-Decorator-Jumbo-Wall-Plate/1001437984) (Lowes link), would do the trick. It mounts to the outlet itself, so screw location wouldn't be an issue, and the jumbo size should cover the outside box.

Comment: For the 14-30 cover plate, you may need to stop by/call your local electrical supply houses to find one in plastic and skip the big-box stores. _If_ all you can find for this cover plate is metal and you're dead set against the metal "look", you could paint it [as suggested](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/242790/matching-outlets-to-junction-boxes-and-their-covers-by-example#comment471813_242790) by Greg Hill, or, possibly cover it with contact paper/wall paper of an appropriate color/pattern. Look for "shelf paper" or "drawer liner paper" for self-adhesive stuff.

Comment: The bounty makes it impossible to close this question, but the comments to the bounty turn it into a shopping question, on top of its inherent flaws.  "Give me links to where I can buy things that meet my aesthetic constraints" is the essence of the question.   The bounty only makes it LESS likely to get an answer I'm afraid.  It would be better to ask 2 or 3 SHORT questions that are actually about how to solve problems.  YOU pick boxes, conduits, and covers that YOU find pleasing, then ask *specific* questions about how to integrate them, and you won't need to offer a bounty.

Comment: Is [this](https://imgur.com/a/qrUAMcw) really so bad?  Pick a nice surface mount system, follow the instructions, everything fits together like Lego and it looks nice.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate You are correct; with 10/3 romex, the conduit needs to be 1.12" inches wide to fit the 53% fill requirement, according to my back of the envelope math.

Comment: I would recommend against using romex in your situation.  If you run romex across the joists, someone is going to want to hang something from the cables at some point.  It sounded silly to me when I read about the possibility, but then it happened to me, and I had to switch to emt anyway.  Plus, as some have mentioned, the conduit will be awkwardly big if you size it correctly for the romex.

Comment: You can carefully remove the jacket from the Romex at the place where it enters the conduit - it's a bit of a fiddly installation, but you can do it. Then it's Romex outside the conduit, and THHN inside. I would add a cable clamp at the mouth of the conduit to keep the wire from moving.

Comment: Have you considered surface raceway (Wiremold)?

Comment: @Ariel -- no it isn't -- there is *no* requirement in the UL standards that the wires in NM be THHN

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Acknowledged. The wires are assumed to be THHN, but are not marked that way, so technically can't be used without the cover with the markings. Obviously there is no safety issue (if there was you couldn't even use them in a j-box), but if you need to pass inspection it might come up - maybe.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Actually .. just found https://standards.incits.org/apps/group_public/download.php/99991/SAV4928.pdf page 50 section 4.4.1.a - not clear to me if that's only if the NM cable has a control cable near it?

Comment: If it's referring to PCS cable, then yeah, it's probably dealing with the control wires inside it

Comment: @jay613 best that can be done is downvote the question...

Comment: Enormous thanks to Ariel for absolutely **killing** it with their answer -- full bounty awarded!!! Also, to the many DIY.SE users here who complained about this question, particularly AuthoritarianWoman and @jay613 (who stated she was predicting that my strategy of offering a large bounty would _not_ result with me getting a quality answer) I would [remind you all of the rules for how 500-point bounties work on the SE platform](https://tinyurl.com/diystackex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this cover: https://www.lowes.com/pd/Hubbell-TayMac-2-Gang-Square-Plastic-Weatherproof-Electrical-Box-Cover/1000391265

And this box: https://www.lowes.com/pd/TayMac-2-Gang-Gray-PVC-Weatherproof-New-Work-Old-Work-Standard-Switch-Outlet-Wall-Electrical-Box/4005491

And this https://www.lowes.com/pd/CANTEX-1-2-in-Combination-Connector-Schedule-40-PVC-Compatible-Schedule-80-PVC-Compatible-Conduit-Fitting/1000321585 threaded adapter from the box to the conduit. This matches what you posted, however I would suggest instead switching to boxes meant for gluing PVC instead:

https://www.lowes.com/pd/CARLON-1-Gang-Gray-PVC-Weatherproof-Old-Work-Standard-Rectangular-Exterior-Electrical-Box/1000975656

Or this: https://www.lowes.com/pd/CARLON-1-Gang-Gray-PVC-Weatherproof-Old-Work-Standard-Rectangular-Exterior-Electrical-Box/1000975662 since you need wire in, and not wire out.

Or this box: https://www.lowes.com/pd/Kraloy-PVC-1-2-in-FSS-Single-Gang-Box-91-Hub-93/5001212815 if you need to daisy chain boxes.

This for the 2 gang: https://www.lowes.com/pd/CARLON-2-Gang-Gray-PVC-Weatherproof-Exterior-New-Work-Old-Work-Standard-Square-Exterior-Electrical-Box/1000975770 (note: It's 1 inch conduit!)

You may find this useful: https://www.lowes.com/pd/Hubbell-TayMac-2-Gang-Rectangle-Plastic-Weatherproof-Electrical-Box-Cover/3772755

I do have to add I'm kind of confused why you are installing a basement with waterproof fixtures. I'm answering the question you asked, but I feel like there are better ways. In particular you really don't need conduit in a basement. Is it just for looks? Because you can just attach a cable clamp to each box, and run the Romex (NM) right to that - there are both waterproof, and non waterproof cable clamps you can use.

1/2" clamp for the regular outlets: https://www.lowes.com/pd/Sigma-Electric-ProConnex-3-8-in-Clamp-on-Type-Service-Entrance-Connector-Conduit-Fitting/1087255 and 1" clamp for the larger box: https://www.lowes.com/pd/Sigma-Electric-ProConnex-1-in-Clamp-on-Type-Service-Entrance-Connector-Conduit-Fitting/1087351

Note that 3/4" will also fit for your 30Amp circuit, so if you are not running conduit, you can get a box with a 3/4" hole.

If you like the waterproof design, then you would use this: https://www.lowes.com/pd/Sigma-Electric-ProConnex-1-2-in-Uf-Cable-Connector-Conduit-Fitting/1087617 for the outlets, and this https://www.lowes.com/pd/Sigma-Electric-ProConnex-1-in-Sealing-Connector-Conduit-Fitting/3389542 for the 10/4 wire for the 30 Amp outlet. (I guessed on the 1 inch size, please have the 10/3 wire with you and test fit it, you might need 3/4 inch instead of 1 inch.)

Note: In both cases (regular and waterproof) you need to switch to boxes with threaded openings, rather than the glued openings for conduit.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133377/discussion-on-answer-by-ariel-matching-outlets-to-junction-boxes-and-their-cover).